# QuickBooks SDK QBFC Com component to fetch deleted records in C#

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

How to fetch only the modified and deleted records from the Quickbook using QBFC COM component in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each individual entity type has it's own modified date filter. For example, the `CustomerQuery` has the `ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.FromModifiedDate` and `ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.ToModifiedDate`. You'll find this pattern in the query message for every entity type and every transaction type.

For deleted records use the `ListDeletedQuery` for entities and `TxnDeletedQuery` for transactions.